# Lenovo Y50-70: How to totally stop the performance throttling when using a non-OEM lower wattage charger?

Tags: cpu, lenovo-laptop, oem, charger, throttling

I have Lenovo Y50-70 (Core i7-4710HQ), and I have to use these days a non-OEM charger with more than 50% lower wattage (65 Watt) than the original charger (135 Watt).

So, are there any more settings in `ThrottleStop` than those in the screenshot I can tweak to fully restore the highest performance I am familiar with when using the original charger?

[image]

P.S. The minimum processor state is set to 100% in case of plugged-in state.

[image]

Comment: You don't due to the inefficient charger you have.

Comment: @Ramhound Can't I make the CPU ignore the weaker supply wattage to give its highest performance?

Comment: No ............

Comment: The original power adapter was able to supply that much power because the computer needed that much power to work. If the manufacturer could get away with a 50% smaller power brick for the same price (or for a lower price to be more competitive), they would.